# Java - 2D arrays - need average for each week, can't figure it out

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The question I was asked is:

Develop an application that accepts from the user, the average rainfall each day for four weeks and stores them in an array. The application should then calculate the average rainfall for each week and store the answers in a separate array. The application should then output the 4 averages to the user. Save the class as RainfallApp.java

This is what I have so far and I can't get it to work. -

```
    public class RainfallApp {
    // int[rows ←→][colums ↑↓] num = new int[][];
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] rain = new int[4][7]; //4 weeks, 7 days
    int[][] average = new int[4][1]; //4 weeks, 1 average of week
    int sum[] = new int[4]; //total rain per week 
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < rain.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < rain[0].length; j++) {
            rain[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value")); //value 
        }
        sum[i] = sum[i] + rain[i][j]; //total of each week

        average[i][j] = sum[i]/rain[i][j];

    }


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average for each week is: "+ average);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With streams you can do this.

```
Stream.of(rain)
    .map(week -> IntStream.of(week).average())
    .filter(OptionalDouble::isPresent)
    .map(OptionalDouble::getAsDouble)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

More conventionally, or if you need the week number, you can do this.

```
for (int weekNum = 1; weekNum <= rain.length; ++weekNum)
{
    OptionalDouble maybeAverage = IntStream.of(rain[weekNum-1]).average();
    if (maybeAverage.isPresent())
    {
        System.out.println("Average for week " + weekNum + ": " + maybeAverage.getAsDouble());
    }
}
```

Comment: Even more beautiful: `Stream.of(rain).map(week -> IntStream.of(week).average()).forEach(oa -> oa.ifPresent(System.out::println));`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line:

```
sum[i] = sum[i] + rain[i][j]; //total of each week
```

`j == 7` causes the `for` loop to stop executing, but you try to access the value of `rain[i][7]` which does not exist. Likewise for the line which follows it (`average[i][j] = sum[i]/rain[i][j];`). You may want to use an additional loop for the computations.

Answer (score 0):

You may use just a 1-dimentional array for average, it will eliminate some of the problem PEF pointed out.

```
    int[][] rain = new int[4][7]; // 4 weeks, 7 days
    // use just a 1-dimensional array for average
    int[] average = new int[4]; // 4 weeks, 1 average of week
    int[] sum = new int[4]; // total rain per week
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < rain.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < rain[0].length; j++) {
            rain[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter value")); // value
            // to add each day’s rainfall, do it inside the loop
            sum[i] = sum[i] + rain[i][j]; // total of each week
        }

        // obtain average by dividing by number of days
        average[i] = sum[i] / rain[i].length;

    }

    // just printing out an array doesn’t give meaningful output. use: 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average for each week is: " + Arrays.toString(average));
```

If you prefer a 2D array for average, just use `average[i][0]` for reading and writing elements. You may want to convert the sum to a `double` before dividing to avoid truncation of the value to an `int`.

It’s not that I don’t like the other answers, I do, I just thought you deserved an explanation of what was wrong in your otherwise nice attempt.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helped a lot. My college doesn't teach arrays on first year, and I'm apparently just meant to know it in second year. So, you're a lifesaver. Thank you so much. I also agree with you with the other answers.